# Media compat Support library

Tags: java, android

I had struck with this issue for last 2 days it shows while starting my project and I had tried so many solutions like gradle updating,build tools version change and `Google Maven repository`.

What went wrong:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':checkview'.
Could not find support-media-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.0.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat/26.0.1/support-media-compat-26.0.1.aar
```

Comment: can you post your gradle and manifest code?

Comment: Hi  kdblue, Got the Answer.Sorry for late reply.

Comment: please update solution here, so that its help other users.